# Appending string in the middle of a text file

Tags: c++, string, file

here is my code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(void){
    fstream myfile2;
    myfile2.open("test2.txt", ios::app);
    string checkline;
    getline(myfile2, checkline);
    int razmer=checkline.length();
    string balli="256";
    myfile2.seekp(razmer);
    myfile2<<balli;

}
```

test2.txt consists of 2 strings, so it is looks like

```
Ivanov
Petrov
```

I want to make from `Ivanov` -> `Ivanov 256`. With no touching 2nd string. But my code did not work at all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly did not work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no easy way to edit a text file. The usual solution is to read the whole source file into memory, make your modifications in memory, and then write out all of the file.

In your example where the file seems to be line-based, you could read it line by line and put the lines in a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Edit the line you want to edit, then loop over the vector and write out the lines.

Note: When writing the file, you open it in write mode, so the file is recreated and looses all old contents.

Comment: But what is wrong with my code? seekp must return a position that i needed, than just write in text file.

Comment: @ratkke If you see e.g. [this `openmode` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) you will see that `app` means "seek to the end of stream before each write". So everything you write will be written at the end, no matter what position the write-pointer is. Also, even if you change the mode, you will simply overwrite the existing data in the file, it will not automatically be moved.